# tidyselect::where() inconsistencies: where is where()?

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyselect

Summary: You can do rename(A=1, B=2), can you do the same using rename_with()? my ~str_replace(... paste0()) works, I don't need to change that. But it only works for one variable at a time. Tidyselect suggests wrapping where(~str_replace...)  but then complains it can't find it even though I can get where() to work in other instances.

I want to implement rename_with for more than one variable, but I get an error `Error: Formula shorthand must be wrapped in` where()`.

```
# Bad
  data %>% select(~str_replace(., "Var_2_", paste0("Issue: Time")))

  # Good
  data %>% select(where(~str_replace(., "Var_2_", paste0("Issue: time"))))
```

Example original:
`test%>% rename_with( ~str_replace(., "Var_2_", paste0("Issue: Time")), ~str_replace(., "Var_3_", paste0("Issue: Time")))`

when I run
`test%>% rename_with(where( ~str_replace(., "Var_2_", paste0("Issue: Time")), ~str_replace(., "Var_3_", paste0("Issue: Time"))))`

and
`test%>% rename_with( where(~str_replace(., "Var_2_", paste0("Issue: Time"))), where(~str_replace(., "Var_3_", paste0("Issue: Time"))))`

I get
`Error in where(~str_replace(., "Var_1_", paste0("Gov't surveillance: video wave")),  :  could not find function "where"`
And I can't find it tabbing through `tidyselect::`

But I can run
`test%>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% map(sd, na.rm = TRUE)`
without any issue so it does exist. What am I doing wrong?

Example data:

```
x <- c("_1_1",
       "_1_2",
       "_1_3",
       "_2_1",
       "_2_2",
       "_2_3",
       "_3_1",
       "_3_2",
       "_3_3",
       "_4_3")
paste0("Var",x)

test <- t(as_tibble(rnorm(10, 5.5, .35)))
colnames(test) <- paste0("Var",x)
```

Comment: Is your `df` same as `test`

Comment: Your example 'test' is a `matrix`.  Can you show the expected output.  Also, the column names showed didn't have `Issue: time`

Comment: If you check the data and the code, the `str_replace` usage within both arguments is not clear as there is no column with 'Issue: Time' in the original data.  So, the assumption is that you want to replace with that substring

Comment: e.g. consider your code `test%>% rename_with( ~str_replace(., "Var_2_", paste0("Issue: Time")), ~str_replace(., "Var_3_", paste0("Issue: Time")))`  Can you describe what exactly it is trying to do?  From the code, it looks like to are trying to remove the 'Var_2_' with 'Issue: Time' while matching the columns that have 'Var_3'  Sorry, it is a bit too confusing

Answer (score 0):

There is a switching of arguments in `rename_with` compared to `rename_at`.  It is a bit unclear about the column names specified in the code and the data showed especially with the `str_replace` in both arguments.  A typical use to replace the column names that starts with 'Var_2' with 'Issue: Time_2' would be

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>% 
    rename_with(~ str_replace(., 'Var_2', 'Issue: Time'), 
       starts_with('Var_2'))
```

-output

```
data
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#  Var_1_1 Var_1_2 Var_1_3 `Issue: Time_1` `Issue: Time_2` `Issue: Time_3` Var_3_1 Var_3_2 Var_3_3 Var_4_3
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    5.68    5.18    5.34            5.38            5.47            5.82    5.93    5.35    5.20    5.62
```

If we need to change multiple column patterns, use `matches`

```
data %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_replace(., '(Var_2|Var_3)', '\\1_Issue: Time'),
         matches('Var_2|Var_3'))
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#  Var_1_1 Var_1_2 Var_1_3 `Var_2_Issue: Tim… `Var_2_Issue: Tim… `Var_2_Issue: Tim… `Var_3_Issue: Ti… `Var_3_Issue: Ti… `Var_3_Issue: Ti… Var_4_3
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    5.68    5.18    5.34               5.38               5.47               5.82              5.93              5.35              5.20    5.62
```

---

Or if we want to change corresponding replacement, pattern, use `str_replace_all`

```
data1 <- data %>%
   set_names(str_replace_all(names(.), c("Var_1", "Var_2"), c("Issue 1 wave", "Issue 2 Wave")))
```

compare the output

```
data1
# A tibble: 1 x 10
  `Issue 1 wave_1` Var_1_2 `Issue 1 wave_3` `Trust Wave_1` Var_2_2 `Issue 2  Wave_3` Var_3_1 Var_3_2 Var_3_3 Var_4_3
                          <dbl>   <dbl>                         <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1                          5.68    5.18                          5.34           5.38    5.47           5.82    5.93    5.35    5.20    5.62
```

with original data

```
data
# A tibble: 1 x 10
  Var_1_1 Var_1_2 Var_1_3 Var_2_1 Var_2_2 Var_2_3 Var_3_1 Var_3_2 Var_3_3 Var_4_3
    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1    5.68    5.18    5.34    5.38    5.47    5.82    5.93    5.35    5.20    5.62
```

---

`where` is generally used to check the column value i.e. suppose we want to select columns that are numeric type, use `select(where(is.numeric))` and not on the column names.  There are select_helpers to find the column names based on a substring i.e. `starts_with`, `ends_with`, `contains`, or pass a regex pattern in  `matches`. An use case of `where` would be

```
data %>% 
   rename_with(~ str_replace(., 'Var_2', 'Issue: Time'), where(~ all(. > 5.5)))

# A tibble: 1 x 10
#  Var_1_1 Var_1_2 Var_1_3 Var_2_1 Var_2_2 `Issue: Time_3` Var_3_1 Var_3_2 Var_3_3 Var_4_3
#    <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>           <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#1    5.68    5.18    5.34    5.38    5.47            5.82    5.93    5.35    5.20    5.62
```

---

In the OP's code, `select/map` can be replaced with `summarise/across`

```
df %>%
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sd))
```

#### data

```
data <- as_tibble(test)
```

Comment: This doesn't address my question: how can I run multiple ~str_replace in a rename_with. The error suggests wrapping where() but adding it to the code throws an error even if where() does function in the map code, *for example*

Comment: @ibm Your input example and the code is confusing because it is using `str_replace` in both arguments and there is no column with substring 'Issue: '

Comment: That's right, I want to do multiple str_replace, one for each variable. There is no column with 'issue', that's the way I'm going to rename my variables. You can do rename(A=1, B=2), can you do rename_with() for more than one variable at a time?

Comment: @ibm Do you want to rename the 'Var_2' and 'Var_3' with `Issue: Time'?

Comment: I can already do that. I want to rename  them (`rename_with`) SIMULTANEOUSLY instead of running the Var_2 code first, then running the Var_3 code.

Comment: @ibm that is not my update.  it is doing simultaneously

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229065/discussion-between-ibm-and-akrun).